# show timer interval refresh in lable on specific format

Tags: c#, winforms

i use the virtual timer in my projects(win form) by 1 hour interval, i can see users time by this format{"hour":"min":"sec"} in countdown mode in label in windows form. can you help me? thanks.

```
Timer Reset_timer = new Timer();
        private void chkactive_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (chkactive.Checked == true)
        {
            Reset_timer.Interval = (int)nmtimervalue.Value * 10000;                                                                                              
            Reset_timer.Enabled = true;
            sw.Start();
        }
        if (chkactive.Checked == false)
            Reset_timer.Enabled = false;
    }
```

Comment: " i can see users time..." "can you help me? " help you with what exactly? please be a little more specific with your problem description

Comment: do you want to create a clock by using **{"hour":"min":"sec"}** format while using `Timer `class in `WinForms`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you want a countdown mode.

1st: Create a timer on winforms.

After this declare a new variable like `private int a = 1800; // 1800/60 = 30 seconds.`

(if you want 1 minute put `private int a = 3600;` (3600 / 60) = 60 seconds.)

2nd: Button to start timer add this code:

```
timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
timer1.Interval = 10;
timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
timer1.Enabled = true;
```

3rd: On your timer1_Tick:

```
a--; //decrementing the timer 1 sec
resultLabel.Text = a / 60 + ":" + ((a % 60) >= 10 ? (a % 60).ToString() : "0" + (a % 60)); //this is a function who gonna returns the remainder of dividing the value of a for 60(seconds), basically to get that smooth countdown ..
```

4th: Button to stop Timer:

```
timer1.Stop();
```

Comment: is this: `resultLabel.Text = a / 60 + ":" + ((a % 60) >= 10 ? (a % 60).ToString() : "0" + (a % 60));` as understandable as it gets? not a single explanation to what this code actually does. you could really boost the quality of your answer by providing a decent explanation...

Comment: Why does `1800; //30 seconds.` correspond to 30 seconds ? and why 3600 to a minute?